# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: partBoundary may not be empty

Tags: java, android

I use org.apache.http library. In build.gradle I import this library:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
```

I always get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: partBoundary may not be empty
```

in this place:

```
    public void setMultipart(List<File> files) {
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Part[] parts = new Part[files.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            try {
                parts[i] = new FilePart("file_" + i, files.get(i));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             
            }
        }
        multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(parts);

   }
```

Comment: **Never** catch exceptions without handle it. Atleast log them

Comment: @Jens thank you for comment. but this does not affect the appearance of the error

Comment: If you get an exception here it will

Comment: I don't get this exception